# Nstableview: validate sender and receiver when dragging and dropping

Tags: validation, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I am implementing drag and drop between two `NSTableViews`. So far I have managed to get the drag and drop to work just fine. However, my specific need is to be able to validate who is initiating the drag and who is accepting the drop. I have more than just the two nsTableViews in my app so I need to make sure the right tables are communicating.

As it turns out, in the validateDrop and acceptDrop methods,

```
- (NSDragOperation) tableView: (NSTableView *)view validateDrop:(id)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op

- (BOOL)tableView: (NSTableView *)view acceptDrop: (id)info row: (NSInteger)row dropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)op
```

the 'view' is the acceptor table in both cases. That is, it is the table receiving the drop. Is there any way to know which table initiated the drag?

I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot simpler than it looks, and I hope that the answer that I found helps someone else

In the method

```
(BOOL)tableView: (NSTableView *)view acceptDrop: (id)info row: (NSInteger)row dropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)op
```

`(id)info` has all the information about the drag-source. So something like

```
         NSTableView *dragSource = [info draggingSource];
```

will give you the dragSource.